# How can i change only a mirrored side of object

Tags: modeling

[image]I am trying to change a vertex position on mirrored side of object bit blender picks the both sides. How can i change an objects only on mirrored side?

Comment: You can't!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: So, what should i do? Redo the whole model?

Comment: That said maybe it's possible with Geometry Node, but you can simply apply the modifier and do the change, how does the object look like?

Comment: You say "I want to change the vertex position...", but why and what do you expect to do?

Comment: I've added an image and there is no "Apply button". Could you say where i can find it?

Comment: I want both sides work independently. Sorry for my poor english

Comment: to apply, either the down arrow top right of the modifier, then choose apply, or having your mouse cursor in the modifier panel ctrl+A. Or in this case, "object/convert/to mesh" menu (in the 3d viewport). But once done, no more mirror... this is up to you..

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated!